# Is concatenation inside an ini file possible?

Tags: php, concatenation, ini

Is there any standard way to concatenate variables of an .ini-file?
The .ini-file is parsed by PHP, so I know that it's possible to do it in PHP, but is it possible inside an .ini-file?

Example for the file:

```
; definition of the server root
[root]
path=/var/path/to/server/root/
url=http://www.domain.xx/
```

And I'd like to define some "subpaths", I'd like something like this:

```
; definition of the server root
[root]
path=/var/path/to/server/root/
url=http://www.domain.xx/

; tree definition
[tree]
upload=/subpath/to/upload/directory/
upload_path=CONCATENATE(root.path,tree.upload)
upload_url=CONCATENATE(root.url,tree.upload)
```

Is this possible?
If not, is there a filetype used for configs where this is possible?

Comment: INI files does not allow you to include any logic, but you can do it by being tricky.  Define upload_path as `upload_path=root.path,tree.upload`. Then in PHP read a value, and do some splitting: `$parts  = explode(",",$uploadPath);` Now you will have and array that will look like this: ['root.path', 'tree.upload']. Now in a loop `foreach($parts as $part) { $blocks = explode( ",", $part);}` With such array you can now build your paths without problems.

Comment: you would  need to expand the `CONCATENATE()` in PHP code. But good idea! +1

Comment: I thought it, unfortunately :-(. @eeree, please move your comment as the answer to check it as the correct one. Thanks to both of you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

INI files does not allow you to include any logic, but you can do it by being tricky. Define upload_path as `upload_path=root.path,tree.upload`. Then in PHP read a value, and do some splitting:
`$parts = explode(",",$uploadPath);`
 Now you will have and array that will look like this: `['root.path', 'tree.upload']`. Now in a loop `foreach($parts as $part) { $blocks = explode( ",", $part);}` With such array you can now build your paths without problems. 
@elefantito

Comment: sadly it does not answer the question that is avout ini files in general... (but may be helpful for those who use it for php)